# Installing Arduino IDE in the new Ubuntu Disco Dingo

Tags: arduino-ide

I tried installing the Arduino IDE in the newly released Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo.
I downloaded the file from the [official downloads page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software). I `chmod +x` ed the file and ran the install script. Then, it says:

```
Adding desktop shortcut, menu item and file associations for Arduino IDE...
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/arduino': No such file or directory
Removing symlink failed. Hope that's OK. If not then rerun as root with sudo.
touch: cannot touch '/root/.config/mimeapps.list': No such file or directory
```

`/usr/bin/xdg-mime: 848: /usr/bin/xdg-mime: cannot create`/root/.config/mimeapps.list.new:
Directory nonexistent`

Then, I again ran it as root user with `su root` but it still gave the same error...

Will this cause a problem..? I mean, I had prior issues related to uploading the sketch in earlier Linux IDE installations. Will this cause a problem...? 
`

Comment: It is not required to run the installer. You may unpack it in a folder (under your $HOME folder, not a system folder) and make a shortcut (symbolic link) to the 'arduino' file. Put the shortcut on the desktop. Perhaps add yourself to the DIALOUT group and perhaps a permission has to be added when using a programmer to burn the bootloader.